# why does the 'cf run-task' command not work on swisscom cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm trying to get 'cf run-task' to work on the swisscom cloudfoundry instance. But it fails with even the simplest command:

```
$ cf run-task hostapp "echo SUCCESS" --name task1
Creating task for app hostapp in org xxx / space yyy as xxx@yyy.com...
Unexpected Response
Response Code: 404
FAILED
```

Is `run-task` not yet supported in cf api version 2.96.0? (which seems to be the current installed version on the swisscom env)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Cloudfoundry Task - Unexpected Response 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606065/cannot-run-cloudfoundry-task-unexpected-response-404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Swisscom Application Cloud has not activated the `cf run-task` feature yet. As of now, it's best to use `cf ssh` and then run the command manually from within your container or include these tasks as idempotent actions in your app's startup script.

`cf run-task` will be enabled in a future release of the Application Cloud.

Comment: thats really unfortunate, on one hand the recommendation is not to use `ssh` to update the DB (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47061859/why-does-cloudfoundry-ssh-drop-the-connection-after-24-minutes?noredirect=1#comment81098786_47061859), but on the other hand `run-task` is disabled. If I have large amount of data for the initial load of a database, then initializing the DB at app start is really not a good idea... are there any plans to activate the feature any time soon?

Comment: @domi what is "large amount of data" in GB and record count? Do you use MariaDB Ent?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov it depends on what kind of env we do a setup for, but it goes can go up to 1G and maybe more in the future. Doing it at the app start, does also mean I have to pack all this data with the application and this for ever, even though I don't need it anymore in old envs. Not having 'run-task' available also means Swisscom env is not compatible with our other env. (pivotal) and we have to implement different scripting solutions for Swisscom.

Comment: @domi thanks. In what format your data? SQL dump? YML?

Comment: @domi is it initial load?

Comment: @FyodorGlebov in XML (liquibase) and yes when we setup a new env then its initial load, but it could also happen that we introduce a new table with the next feature that will also need an initial load. So an "initial load" could happen anytime again, it's just a question of the state the env has a t that time. ...we run multiple different environments and number is growing faster in the future.

Comment: any news here? is there a roadmap for this feature?

Comment: There has been a release at the end of 2018 that enabled this feature. @mastertinner could you please update this post accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @mastertinner Swisscom has since enabled `cf run-task` as part of their application cloud offering. They send out e-mails discussing the release on 22. November 2018, linking to the official CloudFoundry documentation: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html

You can use these commands:

```
cf tasks [APP_NAME]
cf run-task [APP_NAME] [COMMAND]
cf terminate-task [APP_NAME] [TASK_ID]
```